# 'Famous question' list

Tags: discussion

This is not really a question, it is more like the updates on site statistics the mods post sometimes. In case you find it irrelevant, feel free to downvote and or vote for closure.

There is badge titled 'famous question' for questions that attract 10,000 views. Here is a [list of the questions](https://economics.stackexchange.com/help/badges/28/famous-question) that have earned this badge.

I think it is an interesting read, especially if you want to reach a lot of people with your wisdom/attract traffic. There seem to be several distinct types.

1. Students being lazy and/or lost, e.g.

    "Why is AC = MC in the monopoly?",

    "Can A Utility Function Take On Negative Values?" or

    "Derive the average variable cost (AVC) function and show that, when AVC is a minimum, marginal cost (MC) is equal to AVC [closed]". 
    (*This type represents the vast majority of famous questions.*)
2. Non-technical but (IMO) thoughtful questions, e.g.

   "What do supply-demand curves really look like?" or

    "Why aren't house prices included in CPI?"
3. Questions that are political rants or think that economics has the answer to pretty much anything, e.g.

    "People pathologically
   hoard so much cash that they impoverish the entire nation" or

    "How will non-rich citizens make a living if jobs keep getting replaced by robots and are outsourced?"

Comment: I wonder how much of the views were directly referred by a related Google search and how much by the "Hot Network Questions" queue. If the majority was from Google, then that suggests our site is gaining "importance".

Comment: So it's a cross-over between politics.SE (the last set) and math.SE (the first set). Not surprising to me.

Comment: The middle set is more like the conceptual questions on physics.SE.